# Using a Loader for a string of QML

Tags: qt, asynchronous, qml

In Qt 5.3 I've been using the [`Loader`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html) QML element for loading screens, loading the view from a QML file in the background. Now I'm trying to load a **string of QML** dynamically. [`Qt.createQmlObject`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#createQmlObject-method) enables me to do so, but I can't seem to get the `Loader` element to play along.

Seems like `Loader` only takes a URL (`QUrl`) or component (`QQmlComponent`), but `Qt.createQmlObject` creates an object (`QObject`).

I'm new to QML, but from my understanding components are reusable elements, similar to classes, and objects are the instances of those classes. I thus can't seem to wrap my head around why `Loader` wouldn't work with objects.

How can I show a loading screen while (asynchronously) parsing and initializing a string of QML?

Example QML code:

```
Item {
    Rectangle {id: content}

    Loader {id: loader}

    Component.onCompleted: {
        var obj = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtQuick 2.3; Rectangle {}', content);

        loader.source = obj; // Throws error.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible using the current API. As Loader's documentation says, it loads objects via a URL that points to a QML file or a Component:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    Rectangle {
        id: content
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "grey"

        Loader {
            id: loader
            sourceComponent: myComponent
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.margins: 40
        }
    }

    property Component myComponent: Qt.createComponent("MyComponent.qml", Component.Asynchronous)
}
```

**MyComponent.qml:**

```
import QtQuick 2.2

Rectangle {
   color: "red"
}
```

Comment: Hi Mitch, thanks for chiming in. Though this is a good example of a `Loader` loading a QML file, I'm actually looking for a way to apply a `Loader` to a QML string. In other words: is there some way to do `Qt.createComponent(QString string)` rather than `Qt.createComponent(QUrl url)`?

Comment: No, that's what my answer was trying to say. I've updated it.

Comment: Still, there should be some way to load strings of QML asynchronously. Perhaps I need to write a `Loader` subclass. Either way, thanks for your input Mitch.

Comment: No worries. You may want to create a suggestion on bugreports.qt-project.org for this, as well.

Comment: Good call. I just created one: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-39529